# Unable to Verify Smart Contract

Tags: solidity, javascript

Currently I want to make a smart contract for verifying documents. However, I couldn't make it works. I have followed the tutorials as shown here (it is for Solidity 0.4.4 and mine is solidity 0.5.0)

[DoCert](https://github.com/stbeyer/docCertTutorial)

Here is what I've tried.

Notary.sol (edited, following suggestion on comment below)

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;


contract Notary {

  struct Record {
      uint mineTime;
      uint blockNumber;
  }

  mapping (bytes32 => Record) private docHashes;

  constructor() public {
    // constructor
  }

  function addDocHash (bytes32 hash) public {
    Record memory newRecord = Record(now, block.number);
    docHashes[hash] = newRecord;

  }
  function findDocHash (bytes32 hash) public view returns(uint, uint) {
    return (docHashes[hash].mineTime, docHashes[hash].blockNumber);
  }
}
```

app.js

```
function find () {
  hashForFile(function (err, hash) {
    notary_find(hash, function(err, resultObj) {
      if (resultObj.blockNumber != 0) {
        $("#responseText").html("<p>File fingerprint found on Ethereum blockchain.</p>"
            "<p>File Hash Value: "   hash   "</p>"
            "<p>Block No.: "   resultObj.blockNumber   "</p>"
            "<p>Timestamp: "   resultObj.mineTime   "</p>"
        );
      } else {
        $("#responseText").html("<p>File fingerprint not found on Ethereum blockchain.</p>"
            "<p>File Hash Value: "   hash   "</p>"
        );
      }
    });
  });
};
```

notaryWebLib.js

```
function notary_find (hash, callback) {
  contract.methods.findDocHash(hash).call(function (error, result) {
    if (error) callback(error, null);
    else {
      let resultObj = {
        mineTime:  new Date(result[0] * 1000),
        blockNumber: result[1]
      }
      callback(null, resultObj);
    }
  });
};
```

Thank you

Edit :
The problem is the blockNumber is keep saying NULL (as shown below). Sorry I forgot to add it yesterday
[image]

Comment: and what exactly is your problem?`

Comment: to compile your `contract` in `^0.5.0` change `function Notary() public` to `constructor() public`.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the problem log, sorry I forgot to add it yesterday

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0) for SE to distribute that content. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/295232)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `app.js` above, your callback function looks like

```
hashForFile(function (err, hash) {
```

you aren't checking `err` first to see if an error occurred. Usually it's done with something like

```
hashForFile(function (err, hash) {
  if (err) { console.error(err); return }
  ...
}
```

my guess is that you aren't connected to an Ethereum node via a Web3 provider (looks like you're using Metamask).

Comment: Thank you, your answer is helping me to solve the problem. Turns out that it is because I haven't deploy the contract and sync the blocks in the network.

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful! Let us know if you still have problems.